# Liferay configuration with many instances

Tags: liferay, portal

a question about Liferay configuration..

I have found it:

*If you want to expose multiple websites with different domain names from the same portal installation then you will have to create multiple portal instances.
Portal instance can be created from liferay control panel. 
The data for all the instances resides on the same database. Every table in liferay has a column - companyId. For each portal instance there is a unique companyID. This id is ued to distinguish data for multiple websites. You can use sharding technique if we want to physically store data for different instances into different databases.*

**Is possible to create many Liferay instances with separate - data and users data (for login) shared in all liferay instances?**

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are saying you want to have some Users and some data which will be visible in all the Companies or Portal Instances, for eg:

1. There are 3 portal instances: C1, C2 & C3
2. Each instance has users: C1U1, C1U2, C2U1, C2U2, C2U3, C3U2 & so on. These users will be able to login to their respective instances only.

So now you want to create few users like U1, U2, U3 etc which can login to all the 3 liferay instances? That is they would be shared between all the 3 liferay instances or would be independent of the 3 instances?

In the same sense do you want to have Blogs, Wikis etc created that would be visible to users of all 3 liferay instances?

**Solution**
If the above is what you want, then as far as I know there is currently no feature to support sharing among Portal Instances. Sharing data among Sites we have `Global` scope, but we can't have shared users or data among Portal Instances.

All the instances are separated by `companyId`, this `companyId` is present in all the database tables of Liferay to separate the data among portal instances.

As per the [documentation for Portal Instances](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen12-portal-instances-0):

> Data for each portal instance are kept separate from every other portal instance. All portal data, however, is kept in the same database.

So the very philosophy is to have the data separate it seems.

Comment: exactly...
is possible to jump over the problem using this: http://blogs.xtivia.com/home/-/blogs/configuring-liferay-6-1-ee-as-saml-identity-provider-and-service-provider;jsessionid=FAFF978F1276FEAAB48C3A59661BC164?p_p_auth=5uHgTwbp on Liferay EE?

Comment: is possible to jump over this problem with the reimplementing of the CAS (http://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+a+Custom+Authentication+System) ?

Comment: @GgSalent The links you have given are for implementing Single-Sign-on, how would that help in sharing data between portal-instances? For login on a particular instance the User would need to have the `companyId` for that instance. AFAIU you may be able to create the same user for different portal instances (i.e. 3 records in `User_` table with all the columns same but different `companyId`) and then log that user in all the portal instance if he logs in any one. Have not tried just an idea, not sure if this is feasible.

Comment: Also how would you have other data like blogs, wiki share between company instances with this approach?

Comment: probably my suggestion is not good (i'm new in Liferay)..
I thought that each instance can be identy providere to other instances (SSO) to see if the user can authenticate or not.
My problem is this a known issue? as it tries to solve this?